# SVN cannot set property on a directory

Tags: svn

I'm typing via SlikSVN (same happens via TortoiseSVN):

> svn propset svn:eol-style native .

From the repository's root folder, and getting

> svn: Cannot set 'svn:eol-style' on a directory ('.')

with no further explanation. Googling doesn't seem to help either. How do I set this property?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, `svn:eol-style` only makes sense for files, not directories which don't have the notion of end-of-line. If you want to set the property for all versioned files in the directory, use:

```
svn propset svn:eol-style native *
```

or recursively for all versioned files under the current directory and its subdirectories:

```
svn propset -R svn:eol-style native .
```

---

Edit after the comment:

If you want to automatically set props for new files, edit the svn `config` file `auto-props` section to apply properties based on file name patterns.

Comment: I want the property to behave recursively, but I don't want to set it on each of the files recursively, because then new files wouldn't be affected. What's the best practice here?

Comment: This keeps getting upvoted, but nobody is regarding my comment :(

Comment: @ripper234: I did; I updated the answer to mention `auto-props`.